# access denied on member signup with civicrm for anonymous

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, civicrm, civicrm-extension

My question has to do with Civicrm member signup page. I am getting an error for anonymous users that they are not allowed access to the page.

I am using Drupal 7 and CiviCRM 5.3. I am relatively new to Drupal. The site is located on a domain that is being used simply for testing purposes.

I have researched this already and have not received much in the way of finding anyone with a similar issue. Other then seeing posts about user 0. I checked and user 0 is there and seems fine.

As part of trying to resolve the issue I also setup a mock event. Same thing happens on that also. An anonymous user can see the event but as soon as the registration page is clicked it gives the access denied message.

I have also checked the permissions and roles and anonymous is allowed to access the pages. In other words sign up for events and make contributions is checked.
Here is the page for the member signup.

- https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=1
- Event info page : https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org/civicrm/event/info?reset=1&id=1
- Event registration page : https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org/civicrm/participant/add?reset=1&action=add&context=standalone&eid=1

This is the actual site https://hebrewburialofnewhaven.org

Please keep in mind this is only a development site and not a production site. We are testing using Drupal with Civi. Because wordpress has really become very resource intensive and seems to have a lot of issues running civi cleanly.

I thank everyone for any help or guidance on this. It is probably something stupid I am missing or didn’t configure.

Comment: IN general you will get better answers to ask civicrm questions in the civicrm channel ie https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/. Everything you describe above sounds like civicrm permissions and you would need to spell out what you have/have not given - eg there are some 'odd' ones you might not think to offer like 'all custom fields'

Comment: Hi, Thanks I had no idea there was a Civicrm specific page. I posted this same question over there. I will look again at the permissions but I think I got them.